# PWT framework : Twitter Bootstrap version

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gwt, pwt

On which version of [Twitter Bootstrap CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) framework is based [Putnami Web Toolkit framework (PWT)](http://pwt.putnami.org/#!Bootstrap)  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The putnami web toolkit (PWT) is based on twitter bootstrap 3.2.0.
We planned an upgrade to the lastest (v3.3.1) for the next release (PWT 1.2).

You can find the PWT documentation on http://pwt.putnami.org

Answer (score 1):

According to the source https://github.com/Putnami/putnami-pwt/tree/master/core/src/main/resources/fr/putnami/pwt/core/widget/public/theme/default/style, it is Bootstrap 3.2.0